# Sorting a NSMutableArray of strings: 'unrecognized selector sent to instance'

Tags: objective-c

I have made a program that gets some strings in input from the user (it stops typing "exit"), puts them in a NSMutableArray and sort them:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

NSInteger compare( id id1, id id2, void* context)
{
    NSString* str1=[id1 stringValue], *str2=[id2 stringValue]; /* ****** exception here */
    const char* buf1, *buf2;
    buf1=[str1 UTF8String];
    buf2=[str2 UTF8String];
    if(strcmp(buf1,buf2)<0)
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    else
        return NSOrderedDescending;
}


int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    NSAutoreleasePool* pool=[[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];
    NSMutableArray* array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSString* str=@"";
    char buffer[100];
    NSLog(@"Type a sequence of strings, ending with 'exit', the strings will be sorted in alphabethical order");
    while(! [str isEqualToString:@"exit\n"])
    {
        fgets(buffer,100,stdin);
        str=[NSString stringWithUTF8String: buffer];
        [array addObject: str];

    }
    [array sortUsingFunction: compare context: NULL];
    [array release];
    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

But I get an exception in the line that I have marked with "******", it says:

```
2012-05-09 00:10:14.502 CLITest[1029:903] -[NSCFString stringValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10010cbf0
```

It seems like it doesn't take the string value from the id.Why? How should I change the comparator method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`id1` and `id2` are actually `NSString`s, even if they are casted to `id` and passed to your function (this approach is useful because you can define your `compare` function in order to sort custom objects).

It doesn't make sense to call `stringValue` on a string (and, in fact, `NSString` do not have a member function named `stringValue`).

To work with strings just cast  back to `NSString`s.

```
NSString *s1 = (NSString*) id1;
NSString *s2 = (NSString*) id2;
```

This is not strictly necessary (you can even work directly with `id1` and `id2`) but casting will avoid you to get compiler warnings (also it's a clearer code).

Comment: There's no need to cast _and_ assign. The compiler will happily put an `id` into an `NSString *`. You could also just send `UTF8String` to an `id` without the compiler batting an eye, but for readability's sake I agree that you should make the type explicit.